# How to insert hdevtool's type information into source code?

Tags: haskell, vim, types, hdevtools

I try to keep my vim setup light on plugins. For Haskell, all I have is [vim-hdevtools](https://github.com/bitc/vim-hdevtools). I'd like to not have to install anything else.

With vim-hdevtools, I can issue the command `HdevtoolsInfo` and get a separate window with the inferred type of the function the cursor is on.

How do I get Vim to copy that type into my current buffer?

Comment: A feature request to that effect has been [posted](https://github.com/bitc/vim-hdevtools/issues/13) some two years ago.  It's still unsolved.